# Lotus Notes convert formula to agent

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

how do I convert my formula into an agent? I wrote a days left formula in a view and want to make it an agent.

Formula:

```
FIELD DaysLeft := @If(ExpDate = ""; ""; @Integer((ExpDate - @Today)/60/60/24))
```

I have plenty of columns in a view so it will be like:

```
FIELD DaysLeft1 := @If(ExpDate1 = ""; ""; @Integer((ExpDate1 - @Today)/60/60/24))
FIELD DaysLeft2 := @If(ExpDate2 = ""; ""; @Integer((ExpDate2 - @Today)/60/60/24))
FIELD DaysLeft3 := @If(ExpDate3 = ""; ""; @Integer((ExpDate3 - @Today)/60/60/24))
```

Left the Option default:

Declarations:

```
 Dim session As NotesSession
 Dim db As NotesDatabase
 Dim view As NotesView
```

Initialize:

```
Sub Initialize
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Set session = New NotesSession
Set db = session.currentdatabase

FIELD DaysLeft := @If(ExpDate = ""; ""; @Integer((ExpDate - @Today)/60/60/24))

End Sub
```

What should be the code these objects?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything yet???

Comment: That still does not tell me anything.

Comment: Ok, then this is "what should my code be" question and these are off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an agent of type "Formula":

[image]

You can add your formula there. You created a LotusScript agent instead.

[image]

Comment: Hi Knut, thanks. Does Domnio 8.0 have that view? I can't find that option. Edited and posted screenshot.

Comment: You can choose it in the moment of agent's creation only - so **create** the agent again.

Comment: Thank Knut! I'm doing it now. Just repeat the formula if I have multiple right? What SELECT @All is for?

Comment: `SELECT @All` means that  the agent is executed for **all** target's documents. You could add a formula like `SELECT Status="active"` to include documents with this status only.

Comment: Yes, add your other code lines to the formula and add a semicolon `;` at the end of every line.